# CMD C# Windowaplication ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to run something from CMD.
In the C# window.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
//info.Arguments = "/K control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters";
info.Arguments = @"/K cd ../../../../FilesMigration/Solution/FilesMigration/bin/Debug ";
Process.Start(info);
```

It does start the cmd and goes to the specified location, but now I need to run "fileMigration.exe" with its parameters.

I tried like this:

```
info.Arguments = "/K filesmigration \"Data Source=(local)/SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=FilesMigration;Integrated Security=true; Connection Timeout=30\""
                          + " \"C:/Programing/api/PE_API_Tester/FilesMigration/SCD File System/For Ella/K_Root\""
                          + " \"C:/Programing/api/PE_API_Tester/FilesMigration/SCD File System/For Ella/U_Root_Analysis_Clusters\""
                          + " \"C:/Programing/api/PE_API_Tester/FilesMigration/SCD File System/For Ella/U_Root_Analysis_Flows\""
                          + " \"C:/Programing/api/PE_API_Tester/FilesMigration/SCD File System/For Ella/U_Root_AtpSoftware_MatrixAtp\""
                          + " \"notepad\""
                          + " \"CO1\""
                          + " \"V1\"";
Process.Start(info);
```

But it seems like it's searching in the old location. 
I tried "Console.write" also but it doesnt do anything.

Any idea how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead of passing the command yourself

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.WorkingDirectory = @"../../../../FilesMigration/Solution/FilesMigration/bin/Debug ";
info.Arguments = "/K filesmigration ......";
Process.Start(info);
```

Please, check in the link provided the different behavior of this property when the [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx) is false

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property to run your command from selected location.

To run several commands at once you can create batch file (*.bat or *.cmd) and then run this batch file.

Comment: +1 for the batch file approach that I was going to mention in a separate answer.